# What is the best way to create configurable object repository in java?

Tags: java, object, repository

To explain more, what I want is to identify the incoming request based on some parameters in a client server arch. Suppose I receive a request on server which has some parameters like `command=xyz`, `param1=blah`, `param2=blah2`.

`some.property.xyz=com.domain.BusinessFunction1`
`some.property.abc=com.domain.BusinessFunction2`

Now after identifying these parameters, and looking at configurations, i should be able to call the right business function, as in above example, if I received a request in which command param is `xyz`, it should go through `BusinessFunction1` else if it is `abc` it should go through `BusinessFunction2`. And `BusinessFunction1` and `BusinessFunction2` are implemented in two different Java classes.

Comment: Your best approach is to create a singleton factory , which you can populate from a database  `com.domain.BusinessFunction1` stored against the service name `some.property.xyz` , the factory will use reflection to construct the class by using `Class.forName("com.domain.BusinessFunction1");` then you can call a method on this class which takes for ease of use sake a map of property names and values. Personally id create another factory and have specific objects for each business function. If you dont have a database your could store the name value of the business function in an xml or an enum

Answer (score 1):

Your best approach is to create a singleton factory, which you can populate from a database `com.domain.BusinessFunction1` stored against the service name `some.property.xyz`. The factory will use reflection to construct the class by using `Class.forName("com.domain.BusinessFunction1");` then you can call a method on this class which takes for ease of use sake a map of property names and values. Personally I'd create another factory and have specific objects for each business function. If you don't have a database you could store the name value of the business function in an XML or an enum.

Here is the idea using a Singleton and a `HashMap`. I would suggest you populate the factory from a database to give you more flexibility.

**A generic base interface**

```
public interface IBusinessFunction {
    public void doFunction();
    public void setParameters(Map<String,String> paramMap);
}
```

**The Business functions**

```
public class BusinessFunction1 implements IBusinessFunction {
    @Override
    public void doFunction() {
        System.out.println(String.format("Function from business class %s called.", this.getClass().getName()));
    }

    @Override
    public void setParameters(Map<String, String> paramMap) {

    }
}


public class BusinessFunction2 implements IBusinessFunction {
    @Override
    public void doFunction() {
        System.out.println(String.format("Function from business class %s called.", this.getClass().getName()));
    }

    @Override
    public void setParameters(Map<String, String> paramMap) {

    }
}
```

**BusinessFactory**

```
public class BusinessFactory {
    private static BusinessFactory instance = null;
    private Map<String, Class<? extends IBusinessFunction>> businessFunctionMap = null;

    protected BusinessFactory() {
        // Populate this from a database,
        // for the ease of your example i will use a HashMap
        businessFunctionMap = new HashMap<String, Class<? extends IBusinessFunction>>();
        businessFunctionMap.put("some.property.xyz", BusinessFunction1.class);
        businessFunctionMap.put("some.property.abc", BusinessFunction2.class);
    }

    public static BusinessFactory getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new BusinessFactory();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public IBusinessFunction getBusinessFunction(String property) {
        IBusinessFunction businessFunction = null;
        Class clazz = businessFunctionMap.get(property);
        try {
            Constructor constructor = clazz.getConstructor();
            businessFunction = (IBusinessFunction) constructor.newInstance();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      return businessFunction;
    }
}
```

**Test your class and factory**

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        parameters.put("Param1","param 1 value");
        parameters.put("Param2","param 2 value");

        IBusinessFunction businessFunction = BusinessFactory.getInstance().getBusinessFunction("some.property.abc");
        businessFunction.setParameters(parameters);
        businessFunction.doFunction();
    }
}
```